# Assigning inside Text::Xslate template using TTerse syntax

Tags: perl, templates

When I use Text::Xslate template engine and gather data that will be supplied to the template within Perl script, everything works fine and as expected:

```
my %vars = (
    some => {
        nested => {
            thing => 'foobar',
        },
    },
);

# template.tx contains [% some.nested.thing %]
my $content = $tx->render('template.tx', \%vars);
```

As expected, `[% some.nested.thing %]` got replaced by "foobar".
If I assign within template in this way:

`[% some_nested_thing = 'foobar' %]`

everything works fine as well.
But, when I try to assign this way:

`[% some.nested.thing = 'foobar' %]`

it fails with this message: `Text::Xslate::Compiler: Cannot modify ., which is not a lexical variable`.

So, is it even possible in Text::Xslate to assign inside templates like that?

---

It is worthy of note that multidimensional hashes still can be created inside Text::Xslate templates:

```
[% some = {
    nested => {
        thing   => 'foobar',
    }
} %]
```

and then elements in it can be referenced like `[% some.nested.thing %]`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it's not possible like that, and if you read [the MVC paper](http://www.cs.usfca.edu/~parrt/papers/mvc.templates.pdf) the manual links to you'll see why this was an explicit design goal. Passing data back from the view to the controller should be a big no-no. You could always work around that by defining a custom function that you can use to call back to Perl from the template but do think twice if you really really want a hack like this.

Answer (score 2):

[The manual](https://metacpan.org/pod/Text::Xslate::Syntax::TTerse#Misc) only talks about making and assigning new variables, not existing ones. It even discourages using that feature at all.

> SET and assignments, although the use of them are strongly
>   discouraged.
>
> ```
> [% SET var1 = expr1, var2 = expr2 %]
> [% var = expr %]
> ```